# package titlesec error: entered in horizontal mode at each \section{} row

Tags: spacing, errors, titlesec, horizontal, mode

I have the red error bullet **package titlesec error: entered in horizontal mode** at each \section{} instruction row

At the beginning I had the following command, that was causing the error

```
\titleformat{\section}{
  \vspace{-4pt}\scshape\raggedright\large\textbf
}{}{0em}{}[\color{black}\titlerule \vspace{-5pt}]
```

After reading some threads here I changed to use titlespacing, like below , but the error persists.

```
\titleformat{\section}{
  \scshape\raggedright\large\textbf
}{}{0em}{}[\color{black}\titlerule]
\titlespacing{\section}{-0.5cm}{*3.5}{*1.5}
```

I have tried for long and didn't find the solution and it is not allowing the pdf file to be generated.

could you please help to solve the issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're trying to use `\textbf` in `\titleformat`, but `\textbf` is a command that takes an argument, it's not a command used without arguments to switch the font to bold. You should rather use `\bfseries` there.

The following example compiles without error.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\titleformat{\section}{
  \vspace{-4pt}\scshape\raggedright\large\bfseries
}{}{0em}{}[\color{black}\titlerule \vspace{-5pt}]
\begin{document}
\section{A section}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Font changing commands come in two varieties:

- actions (e.g., `\textbf`, `\textsc`);
- declarations (e.g. `\bfseries`, `\scshape`).

The former type commands take an argument, the latter type commands don't.

So `\textbf{foo}` typesets “foo” in boldface (actually, it adds the boldface attribute to the current ones), but has no effect whatsoever on the surrounding text.

To the contrary, `\bfseries` tells LaTeX that, from this point on, *all* text will be typeset in boldface (additionally to the other font attributes). However, the effect is scoped by groups, so it doesn't really go on forever.

When a section title is typeset, LaTeX is always inside a group, because typically a title sets special font attributes that we don't want to go on forever.

Thus selecting font attributes in the arguments to `\titleformat` is safe. But the commands you use must be *declarations*, not actions.

Hence not `\textbf`, which you discovered leads to low level errors, because this command actively looks for its argument and uses some random unexpected token. You should use `\bfseries`, just like you use `\scshape`.

Beware that most fonts don't have boldface small caps, but even if your favorite font does, you'd be doubly emphasizing the title. One layer of emphasis is sufficient, so you should decide between boldface and small caps, not both. But this is a stylistic decision that I leave to your taste. By the way, the title rule adds another layer of emphasis, so you end up with *three*.

Also, spacing should be set with `\titlespacing`, not with explicit vertical spacing commands in `\titleformat`. With the code you propose, you add a fourth layer of emphasis, namely that the section title sticks in the left margin.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\usepackage{libertinus} % for boldface small caps
\usepackage{lipsum} % for context

\titleformat{\section}
  {\filright\large\scshape\bfseries}
  {\thesection.\ }
  {0em}
  {}
  [\titlerule]

\titlespacing{\section}{-0.5cm}{*3.5}{*1.5}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-4]

\section{Some section title}

\lipsum[2-3]

\end{document}
```

Note `\filright` instead of `\raggedright` and the omission of `\color{black}` that does nothing (unless you're also setting a different color for the title, which would add a further layer of emphasis).

[image]